# What is a ~ (tilde) when used as a prefix to a path?

Tags: command-line, osx

Edit: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory/.  I don't have the reputation to close this question as duplicate.

I'm not referring to `~` as in the home directory but rather this:

```
$ ls ~foo/bar
/some/mount/point/foo/bar
```

However if I attempt it with a different mount point, e.g.:

```
$ mount | ag "/dev "
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
$ ls /dev/stdin
/dev/stdin
$ ls ~stdin
zsh: no such user or named directory: stdin . 
# bash has a similar error message: 
ls: ~stdin: No such file or directory
```

What is the `~` called in this context?  How does it work?

Edit:
More information based on some of the comments below:

1. I can attest that `foo` is not a username on my system.
2. When attempting to autocomplete `ls -lah ~` not all options are shown.  i.e. I'm able to `cd ~qux`, when `qux` doesn't show up in the autocomplete.  Again `qux` is not a user in my system.
3. If it matters `/some/mount/point` is a network share.
4. All of the details suggest some named path muckery, a Z shell feature of pathname expansion, but this works in bash as well, which apparently doesn't support things like the Z shell's named paths.

Comment: `~foo` is the home directory of the user `foo`.  If the user is not specified, the current user is the default.

Comment: But in this case, `/some/mount/point` definitely isn't my home directory.  `cd ~` takes me to `/Users/$username/`--which matches `$HOME`

Comment: `zsh` appears to also use the tilde to indicate named directories.

Comment: I suspected that too!!  Except for some reason the series of commands I posted above works in bash as well (`bash -c "ls ~foo/bar"`)--which doesn't have named directories.  Furthermore even within zsh, if I inspect the `env`, I don't see any named directories set up.  I'm on Mac OS and I feel this is some feature specific to OS X.

Comment: You only said `~foo`. Take the actual string (not the example `foo` ) and do `grep "actual username" /etc/passwd`. `~text` should work for only *possible* login usernames according to bash manual (doesn't necessarily mean it is actually able to log in; in case of system users such as `~lp` , for example).  In all my tests, the `~string` corresponds with `string` being username.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I can confirm that `foo` is not a user in `/etc/passwd`.  More details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423962/what-is-a-tilde-when-used-as-a-prefix-to-a-path#comment763801_423983.  FWIW, I'm being intentionally vague with paths as I see with my work computer and sharing the real path would likely reveal personal info.

Comment: zsh "named directories" are explained in zshexpn(1) under "Dynamic named directories" and "Static named directories" - has anyone actually tried looking at the manual?

Comment: @R.D. What about `/etc/master.passwd` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was '~' chosen to represent the home directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/why-was-chosen-to-represent-the-home-directory)

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge    Wrong duplicate link. Your link talks about history of tilde alone. This question talks about tilde expansion (which is more features than just expanding to user's home), and at least according to OP there is some unknown behavior for tilde expansion.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You're correct. Retracting my close vote. It was my oversight.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, no luck in /etc/master.passwd.  I just grepped the entirety of `/etc` for instances of `foo` (or similar paths I'm able to access)--no dice

Comment: @R.D. see RJHunter's and Abigail's comments under my answers. You might consider trying `getent`

Comment: @R.D. can you `grep -Fr some/mount/point /etc` ? [without any **foo** part, just the mount point itself; it may be listed somewhere as a default location for creating user directories]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory

Comment: @JulienLopez I believe that's getting me closer!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068161/639069 is spot on to my situation.  Researching further, https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch09_04.htm perfectly describes what's going on my machine.  Unfortunately, none of the mentioned configuration files contain what I'd expect it to.  I'm going to mark this question as a dupe of the one you pointed to and hopefully contribute with a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### What is ~foo

Quote from [bash manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) (with added emphasis):

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted  slash  (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix  following the tilde are treated as a **possible** login name.

`~foo`  expands to `foo` user's home directory exactly as specified in `/etc/passwd`. Note, that this can include system usernames; it doesn't necessarily mean human users or that they can actually log in locally ( they can log in via SSH keys for instance).

In fact, as noted in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423962/what-is-a-tilde-when-used-as-a-prefix-to-a-path/423984?noredirect=1#comment763846_423984), `bash` will use `getpwnam` function. That function itself is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwnam.html) standard, hence should exist on most Unix-like systems, including [macOS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423123/85039). This function isn't limited to `/etc/passwd` only and searches other databases, such as LDAP and NIS. Particular excerpt from `bash` [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/tilde/tilde.c), `tilde.c` file, starting at line 394:

```
  /* No preexpansion hook, or the preexpansion hook failed.  Look in the
     password database. */
  dirname = (char *)NULL;
#if defined (HAVE_GETPWNAM)
  user_entry = getpwnam (username);
#else
  user_entry = 0;
```

---

#### Practical example

Below you can see tests with system usernames on my system. Pay attention to corresponding `passwd` entry and result of `ls ~username`

```
$ grep '_apt' /etc/passwd
_apt:x:104:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
$ ls ~_apt
ls: cannot access '/nonexistent': No such file or directory
$ grep '^lp' /etc/passwd
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ ls ~lp
ls: cannot access '/var/spool/lpd': No such file or directory
```

Even if for instance `_apt` account is locked as suggested by output of `passwd -S apt` it is still showing up as possible login name:

```
_apt L 11/29/2017 0 99999 7 -1
```

**Please note:** This is not macOS specific feature, but rather shell-specific feature.

Comment: I doubt the shell can rely on finding out anything about the account expiration date or if it's locked or anything when expanding the tilde. E.g. on Linux, the expiration date is stored in `/etc/shadow`, along with the other protected authentication information, like the password. The reference in `passwd` is just about making the password invalid: that would not prevent authentication through other means.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yep, you're right. I've tested that with adding `testuser` and modifying password expiration date.  The username still appears in tab completion. I've removed that bit from the answer

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it quotes the `bash` man page (and old one at that, it seems). The OP is actually using `zsh` (could have been clearer), though in the comments it is mentioned that `bash` has the same behaviour.

Comment: You can use `getent passwd foo` instead of `grep foo /etc/password` to follow the same lookup mechanisms as the shell - perhaps including network-based directory services that @Abigail mentions.

Comment: Accepted as answer for the 'such as LDAP and NIS' bit, which ended up being correct in my case!

Answer (score 7):

In summary of why you are seeing something for `~foo/bar`, it is because you have a user named `foo` on the system with a folder named `bar` in their home directory.

See [this solution in another community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory#answer-1660054) that explains why (tilde) `~` is more than just "home directory".

If you have a user named `bin` on your system, then you can list the contents of *bin's home directory* by the command:

`ls ~bin`

One other thing you can try is to use tab completion after typing the following at a prompt (don't carriage return, just use the tab key):

`ls -lah ~` <kbd>tab</kbd>

to see the list of users' home directories that `~` will expand to if you continue to.  Example (truncated) output of tab completion of `ls -lah ~` <kbd>tab</kbd>

```
$ ls -lah ~ [tab]
~antman/            ~games/
~bin/               ~mail/
```

Comment: +1 for tab completion. This clearly reveals all the usernames that bash can get as possible login names from `/etc/passwd`. It immediately helps to clarify what is going on if the user of course is aware of the usernames they have on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the bash completion--resulted in some interesting autocomplete results.  While `~foo` did autocomplete, I can attest that `foo` is not a user on my system (and indeed doesn't exist in `/etc/passwd`).  Furthermore, all the folders/files in `/some/mount/point` show up in the autocomplete which is super interesting.