# What is a file that exists on all unix systems?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to run a script which downloads a file from a VM, but I cannot specify the VM that is passed in. However, I want to ensure that the download is successful regardless of the state of the passed in VM, and I know it is a unix/linux system.

My question is - is there a specific file I can use to download that would be guaranteed to exist on all unix/linux systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be a file that is guaranteed _not_ to exist on non-UNIX/Linux systems?

Comment: @roaima Nope, doesn't matter if it exists on non-unix/linux systems :)

Comment: I'd suggest `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/passwd`, but I can't guarantee this so not providing a "proper" answer. See [Is the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard a UNIX standard or a GNU/Linux standard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98751/is-the-filesystem-hierarchy-standard-a-unix-standard-or-a-gnu-linux-standard).

Comment: Maybe `/etc/profile`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/etc/passwd` is commonly used by [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/92766/121824) professionals as proof of concept/ flag capture exercise, and for a good reason - this file exists on every unix like system.

However, this is worth noting that it doesn't mean `passwd` will be the main access database, as [other databases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423984/85039) such as LDAP play a role, too.

Comment: I *think* this answer makes more sense than the other...

Comment: The thing is, `/etc/passwd` is not guaranteed to exist, as it's possible to move `/etc`, which is the main point of my answer.

Comment: @DopeGhoti  It's absolutely true, but 1) is it a normal occurrence and unix filesystem hierarchy standard exists just for lols and giggles, or is the owner of the system consciously moving /etc somewhere else ? 2) POSIX doesn't guarantee it but `pwd.h`  and the fact that this file exists on even older versions of *nix systems makes it a good candidate.  I'm sure both your and this answer can be beneficial, it's just the question of context.

Comment: Also this https://github.com/hak8or/Embedded-Linux-System/blob/master/at91sam9n12/gists/kernel-booting-without-rootfs.txt

Comment: I agree; it's just that magic word 'guaranteed' in the question that makes it a hard question to answer.  It's kind of a shame an OP can't split their acceptance between to equally valid answers (:

Answer (score 14):

Just about the only thing that's *guaranteed* to exist is the root directory itself.  There are a *lot* of standards that are *almost universally* adhered to, but it's entirely possible for a bored systems engineer to roll out a Linux build where `/etc` lives in `/andsoforth`, `/bin` lives in `/cupboard`, `/usr` lives in `/luser`, and so forth.  In such a system, all bets are off.

Comment: +1 for `/andsoforth` and `/cupboard`.  Thanks for all the Ghoti.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is almost sure to exist. You'll find `/bin/sh` most of the time, directories `/lib` (or perhaps `/lib64`), and also `/usr`, `usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and perhaps `/usr/lib64`

Comment: You're missing the point of my answer entirely in that while any system _that conforms to the well established standard_ will indeed have `/bin/sh` and `/etc/passwd`, they are in fact _not_ **guaranteed** to exist at those locations.  If `/etc` is moved by a sufficiently bored/deviant/creative administrator to `/et_cetera`, then the `passwd` file now lives at `/et_cetera/passwd` and `/etc/passwd` does not exist.

Comment: @vonbrand, and then some joker hands you a copy of [GoboLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoboLinux), and you find yourself using `/Programs/bash/5.0/bin/bash` as the default shell.

Comment: When I saw the title of the question, I immediately thought of GoboLinux, I just couldn't remember it's name.

Comment: @vonbrand being Unix or Unix-like doesn't mean that [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is used

Answer (score 2):

[POSIXly, the only things that are promised](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap10.html) ("shall exist on conforming systems") are `/`, `/dev`, `/tmp`, `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty` and `/dev/console`, though not all may be writable (or even readable).

Depending on what you use to copy the files, all that is either really not helpful, or you could try to copy `/dev/null`. `scp` seems to give an error when trying to copy it, but if you use something that just reads the data and ignores the file being special, like `cp /dev/null .`, you end up with a successfully copied zero-length regular file.

But if you try to copy it with something copies the device node, you probably can't create it on the local system without privileges, and I don't think there's any guarantee the device numbers are the same across systems, so if you can copy it, the result might be a device node that means something completely different on the local system.

The standard utilities are supposed to be in `PATH`, so if you can parse that on the remote, you should be able to find e.g. `sh` or `ls` in some listed directory (though they might be symlinks). On a conforming system, you should also be able to find `cd`, but Linuxes don't tend to have it, since it's  pretty much useless as an external utility.

In practice, you'll probably find `/bin/ls` or `/bin/sh` in many systems (though they still might be symlinks). Maybe not on the most esoteric ones, but you probably know if you're dealing with those.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience:

- `/dev/stdout`, although that's sometimes a symlink, so `/dev/null` might be better, although neither of these is a plain file
- `/etc/hosts` and probably `/etc/resolv.conf` would have to exist for any UNIX system that is networked
- `/bin/sh` and `/bin/init` are highly likely to exist, but I can imagine some embedded Linux systems or Linux-powered appliances and NAS boxes could have one of these in a different location, or be a symlink (eg to `/bin/busybox`) rather than a file; although `/etc/inittab` is perhaps more likely to exist AND be a plain file
- `/etc/issue` and `/etc/profile` seem to exist everywhere that anyone can login to a shell.

Comment: I wouldn't count on `/bin/init`: my Gentoo system has it as `/sbin/init`, and I've seen plain `/init` used by some systems.

Comment: As @DopeGhoti has pointed out, `/etc` can be renamed by a suitably pathological or paranoid administrator. `/dev` could also be changed. Very non-standard but the key word in the question is "guaranteed".

Comment: I'm not sure `/etc/hosts` is really required, even on a "normal" OS. `resolv.conf` looks to be rather common, though. I think `inittab` is tied to SysV-style init, and not all systems might have it. At least the ["FreeBSD Quickstart Guide for Linux® Users"](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/linux-users/) (from 2008, on freebsd.org) says "Under the BSD-style init(8), there are no run-levels and /etc/inittab does not exist." Systemd probably doesn't require `inittab` either, I guess?